# Why does $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} |x-b|f(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^b(b-x)f(x)dx+\int_{b}^{\infty}(x-b)f(x)dx$?

Tags: probability, improper-integrals, absolute-value, expected-value

I am working on the following problem:

> Let $X$ be a random variable of the continuous type that has pdf $f(x)$.  If $m$ is the unique median of the distribution of $X$ and $b$ is a real constant, show that $$E(|X-b|)=E(|X-m|)+2\int_{m}^{b} (b-x)f(x)dx,$$ provided that the expectations exist.

Since $X$ has a pdf of $f(x)$, I know that the expectation of $E(|x-b|)$ is defined as $$E(|x-b|)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty |x-b|f(x)dx.$$  Where I'm getting stuck is the step that immediately follows this.  Specifically, the solution provided shows:

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty |x-b|f(x)dx=\int_{-\infty}^b(b-x)f(x)dx+\int_{b}^\infty (x-b)f(x)dx.$$  What is happening in this step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are splitting up the integral into two integrals corresponding to the two cases:

1. If $x \le b$, $|x-b| = b-x$.
2. If $x > b$, $|x-b| = x-b$.

Comment: Does this work regardless of the sign of $b$?

Comment: Consider case 1. The sign of $b$ is already taken into account by $x \le b$. For example if $b = -3$, $x=-4$ works but $x = -2$ doesn't

Comment: Thanks for the example, @Mark!  I know it was a really basic question.